# Why is everyone sleeping in the captain's quarters?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, guardians-of-the-galaxy, guardians-of-the-galaxy-2

In *Guardians of the Galaxy: Vol. 2*,

> Tazerface takes over Yondu's ship. Yondu and Rocket get locked up, but are able to send baby Groot to look for Yondu's new fin in the Captain's quarters.

When baby Groot gets to the captain's quarters, perhaps more than a dozen people are sleeping on the floor together.

**Is this normal for ravagers? Are there other examples of ravagers sleeping in packs?**

Comment: They had just had a mutiny-themed party, most likely they all passed out there out of pure joy and exuberance... err I mean alcohol...

Comment: Wasn't it technically an old one? The prototype, as I remember.

Comment: @JAB I thought that prototype implied replacement.

Comment: I thought it implied it was the original, a fallback.

Comment: @Mooz I think your comment should be posted as an answer. It's a short, sweet, and logical explanation.

Comment: @StevenVascellaro - BAH!  Who needs 'short' answers?

Comment: @mooz if you post your original comment as an answer, I will mark it as accepted and+1.

Comment: @CodeMed Done. pls review.

Comment: @CodeMed - he did, and his answer has a video of Baby Groot.  Obviously superior, and he *does* deserve the accepted answer - he said it first (in comments) and I simply expanded upon it.  His OOU answers are also very nice.

Comment: @Jeff thank you, you're a great sport.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## They were passed-out after having a partaayyy

Officially, there is no explanation given, the relevant scene(s) don't provide context, and the junior novelisation is no help. We'll have to await the [official script](https://twitter.com/JamesGunn/status/891016780767928320) for any more info.

However, there are actually a few explanations which we can gleam for this, both in and out of universe.

### In-universe

The best explanation we have is as I mentioned in the comments, they had just had a successful mutiny and had celebrated, *with tons of alcohol*. As you can see in [this related scene](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hTyR_z_msaU) the crew were rowdy as and had been drinking shite-loads of alcohol. This tends to end in people being tired and generally passing out where they are.

You can also see them drinking and spilling alcohol here:

[2:52]

### Out-of-universe

There are a couple of explanations here:

1. **Comedic relief**
   Seeing them all sprawled out and lying on top of each other is a known hilarious joke in a '[WhatDidIDoLastNight](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/WhatDidIDoLastNight)'<sup>#</sup> kind of way. This also sets up the scene where Baby Groot is trying to retrieve the prototype fin for Yondu and has to sneak past the crew members and makes the scene really tense:

   - Is he going to wake one up and ruin the whole plan?
   - Will he finish on time before they all wake up?
   - How on earth did he sneak a table past them?
   - Who's toe was that?????
2. **Round 'em up**
   Much of the next sequence requires for the crew to be in the same place and in disarray. Kraglin was conveniently in place to witness Groot's tirade and was able to step in and help.

   Once Yondu gains control of his arrow via his prototype fin, with the help of Kraglin, he is then able to quickly kill the remaining crew members who are all conveniently located in the one area of the ship. Rocket helps by hanging out in the control room whilst easily picking crew members off. Kraglin is able to detach the 3<sup>rd</sup> quadrant, which is again conveniently empty.

---

<sup>**#** If you're wondering why it took me so long to answer, it's because I was trapped in the depths of TV-Tropes. Now, it's your turn suckers, see you next week!</sup>

Comment: Once you pass 30k rep, you become immune to TVTropes, due to overexposure.  You're almost there!  (Also, I'm lying.  I got sucked in too)

Answer (score 4):

There is no strong evidence one way or another for this being typical behavior.

On the one hand, we have on-screen evidence of it occurring at least once (in the referenced scenes).  So we know it has happened at least once.

On the other hand, that scene follows a mutiny where most of the established patterns of leadership and behavior were overthrown, to the extent that summary executions of the old guard were occurring.  This culminated in the mutineers having a massive party, most likely taking great pleasure in disrespecting the 'establishment'.

If Hollywood is to be believed (and in this case, as we are using it as a meter-stick for a Hollywood movie, it is!) these parties frequently end with everyone appropriately clothed (excepting, perhaps, one person for comedic effect) scattered willy-nilly about the place.

So there's a good explanation for why this could be atypical behavior.

There is, however, moderately good evidence against this being typical Ravager behavior:

In GotG 1, Peter Quill (who was raised by the ravagers from a fairly young age) ends up in a prison.  Most prisoners there sleep in large groups in the center of the room.  Peter seemed to be distinctly uncomfortable with this, and certainly did not seem used to it.

Thus, while we can't be certain either way, it seems likely that it is not normal behavior for the Ravagers.

Comment: The example from GotG1 adds insight enough to build an answer around. All your other text could be reduced to 2 or 3 sentences to become more readable.

Comment: @CodeMed - I'm almost physically incapable of giving a short answer.  But I do try to include relevant details and walk people through how I arrived at conclusions not directly stated in canon.

Answer (score 1):

It is my belief that, while Taserface had decided that he was the leader, the other Ravagers still saw the chance to go and rifle through their ex-Captain's things. And with the Captain's quarters possibly having been off-limits prior to the mutiny, so many of them wanted to play around there and not even Taserface could stop them. I think it kind of shows how poor of a leader Taserface was when he couldn't keep everyone out of the quarters that he should have been able to claim for himself.

Then the previously-discussed party happened, and many of them simply passed out there in a big, smelly Ravager cuddle-pile.

Comment: Welcome to SFF:SE. We recommend having a look at the [tour](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour), which contains helpful hints for using the site.

Comment: @Politank Perhaps, but this user did add insight. +1 for the insight, even if a more seasoned user would have looked up some documentation.